# Machine learning regression when you only know the product of the truth values

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network

Suppose I want to model an unknown function $f$ knowing a set of pair $\{ x_i, y_i\}_i^N$ where $x_i\in \mathbb{R}^D$ and $y_i\in \mathbb R$ such that $y_i=f(x_i)$. This is the classical problem of regression.

My problem is more complicated. I know $\{ x_i^{(1)},  x_i^{(2)}, z_i\}_i^N$ such that $f(x_i^{(1)}) \times f(x_i^{(2)}) = z_i$. (The problem can be generalized to $g(f(x_i^{(1)}), f(x_i^{(2)})) = z_i$ where $g$ is known, in my actual problem it is $g(a, b) = \sqrt{ab}$).

Using the L2 metric I should minimize

$\sum_i|\hat f(x_i^{(1)}) \times \hat f(x_i^{(2)}) - z_i|^2$

where $\hat f$ is my algorithm (let say a neutral network).

Question 1. Has this kind of problem a name?

Question 2. How practically implement that? This is similar to a convolution since you are reusing the same network (not just one layer) on different inputs (you can represent your inputs as element of $\mathbb{R}^{2D}$. Using a package as tensorflow is it possible to duplicate a NN (let say a simple feed forward with few layers) but to say the the weights are the same in the sense that they are really the same variable?

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: I don't know but don't think it has a specific name.

Question 2: What you are describing is called weight sharing, where, as the name indicates, is when the same weights of your network are shared among different features. You are right in saying that it is similar to convolution as this is exactly what convolution does across spatial dimensions. It should fairly easy to implement in tensorflow here is some spaghetti code assuming two distinct column like features $x_1$ and $x_2$:

```
x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))
x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 1))

weights = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1, 1], stddev=1.0))
biases = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.0, shape=[1])

f1 = weights * x1 + biases
f2 = weights* x2 + biases

g = tf.sqrt(f1 * f2)
```

And afterwards just plug $g$ into your loss, I believe you either forgot to include $g$ in the l2 loss or that $g$ does not correspond to $z_i$ but this is a minor detail.

Good luck.